# Usage of _call for protected methods in PHP

Tags: php, oop

I have protected methods (`Set_SelectedElementStyle` and `Set_SelectedElementAttribute`) that accept some (exactly 4 - but last is not demanded) arguments.

Those arguments are:

- order - number that means index of element that will get some attributes or styles
- element - element
- name - name of attribute or style
- value - value of attribute or style (not demanded - then style is ignored and attribute may be empty)

I thought that I would use *not-existing* function with name would containing name of element and word *style* or *attribute* (that would mean which of above called method will be used) to simplify their calling.

Argument *order* would be prepared and set inside method `__call` I wanted to use to call that not-existing method.

Calling of not-existing function could be (for example - but this is non-sense - because XML tag does not need formatting)

```
$this -> Person_Style('font-family', 'Arial');
```

But I read elsewhere in Stackoverflow that this leads to FATAL error.

So, what else way to use to call those protected functions in a way I thought.

Edit:

one of two protected methods with four arguments

```
protected function Set_SelectedElementStyles($Order, $Element, $Name, $Value="")
{
    try
    {
        if(empty($Order) && $Order != 0)
        {
            throw new MarC_Exception(UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_MAIN_CLS, UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_MAIN_FNC, UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_MAIN_PRM, UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_SEC_PRM_MISSING);
        }
    }
    catch(MarC_Exception $Exception)
    {
        $Exception -> ExceptionWarning(get_called_class(), __FUNCTION__, $Exception -> Get_Parameters(__CLASS__, __FUNCTION__)[0]);
    }

    try
    {
        if(!is_integer($Order))
        {
            throw new MarC_Exception(UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_MAIN_CLS, UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_MAIN_FNC, UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_MAIN_PRM, UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_SEC_PRM_WRONGVALTYPE);
        }
    }
    catch(MarC_Exception $Exception)
    {
        $Exception -> ExceptionWarning(get_called_class(), __FUNCTION__, $Exception -> Get_Parameters(__CLASS__, __FUNCTION__)[0], gettype($Order), 'integer');
    }

    try
    {
        if($Order < 0)
        {
            throw new MarC_Exception(UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_MAIN_CLS, UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_MAIN_FNC, UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_MAIN_PRM, UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_SEC_PRM_LOWNUMBER1);
        }
    }
    catch(MarC_Exception $Exception)
    {
        $Exception -> ExceptionWarning(get_called_class(), __FUNCTION__, $Exception -> Get_Parameters(__CLASS__, __FUNCTION__)[0], 0);
    }

    try
    {
        if(empty($Element))
        {
            throw new MarC_Exception(UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_MAIN_CLS, UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_MAIN_FNC, UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_MAIN_PRM, UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_SEC_PRM_MISSING);
        }
    }
    catch(MarC_Exception $Exception)
    {
        $Exception -> ExceptionWarning(get_called_class(), __FUNCTION__, $Exception -> Get_Parameters(__CLASS__, __FUNCTION__)[1]);
    }

    try
    {
        if(empty($Name))
        {
            throw new MarC_Exception(UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_MAIN_CLS, UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_MAIN_FNC, UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_MAIN_PRM, UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_SEC_PRM_MISSING);
        }
    }
    catch(MarC_Exception $Exception)
    {
        $Exception -> ExceptionWarning(get_called_class(), __FUNCTION__, $Exception -> Get_Parameters(__CLASS__, __FUNCTION__)[2]);
    }

    /*
     * sets styles;
     * Element - element name;
     * Order - number of position of element that will get style;
     * Name - style name;
     * Value - style value
    */
    $this -> ElementStyles_Selected[$Element][$Order][$Name] = $Value;
}
```

that is called by public method where two of four arguments are *extracted* from other conditions

```
public function __call($Function, array $Parameters)
{


    $Options = array('Element_Style', 'Element_Attribute');

    try
    {
        if(!in_array($Function, $Options))
        {
            throw new MarC_Exception(UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_MAIN_CLS, UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_MAIN_FNC, UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_MAIN_PRM, UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_SEC_PRM_DMDOPTION);
        }
    }
    catch(MarC_Exception $Exception)
    {
        $Exception -> ExceptionWarning(get_called_class(), __FUNCTION__, $Exception -> Get_Parameters(__CLASS__, __FUNCTION__)[0], $Options);
    }

    if($Function == $Options[0])
    {
        $Element = split('_', $Function)[0];

        if($Element == $this -> Elements['top'])
        {
            call_user_func_array(array($this, 'Set_SelectedElementStyles'), array_unshift($Parameters, 0, $Element));
        }
        else
        {
            call_user_func_array(array($this, 'Set_SelectedElementStyles'), array_unshift($Parameters, array_flip($this -> Elements['sub'])[$Element], $Element));
        }
    }
    else
    {
        $Element = split('_', $Function)[0];

        if($Element == $this -> Elements['top'])
        {
            call_user_func_array(array($this, 'Set_SelectedElementAttributes'), array_unshift($Parameters, 0, $Element));
        }
        else
        {
            call_user_func_array(array($this, 'Set_SelectedElementAttributes'), array_unshift($Parameters, array_flip($this -> Elements['sub'])[$Element], $Element));
        }
    }
}
```

or else (and elsewhere - in else class) public method for usage of protected one written above. This accept three arguments.

```
public function Set_SubLevelAttributes($Order="", $Name="", $Value="")
{
    try
    {
        if(empty($Order) && $Order != 0)
        {
            throw new MarC_Exception(UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_MAIN_CLS, UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_MAIN_FNC, UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_MAIN_PRM, UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_SEC_PRM_MISSING);
        }
    }
    catch(MarC_Exception $Exception)
    {
        $Exception -> ExceptionWarning(get_called_class(), __FUNCTION__, $Exception -> Get_Parameters(__CLASS__, __FUNCTION__)[0]);
    }

    try
    {
        if(!is_integer($Order))
        {
            throw new MarC_Exception(UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_MAIN_CLS, UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_MAIN_FNC, UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_MAIN_PRM, UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_SEC_PRM_WRONGVALTYPE);
        }
    }
    catch(MarC_Exception $Exception)
    {
        $Exception -> ExceptionWarning(get_called_class(), __FUNCTION__, $Exception -> Get_Parameters(__CLASS__, __FUNCTION__)[0], gettype($Order), 'integer');
    }

    try
    {
        if($Order < 0)
        {
            throw new MarC_Exception(UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_MAIN_CLS, UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_MAIN_FNC, UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_MAIN_PRM, UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_SEC_PRM_LOWNUMBER1);
        }
    }
    catch(MarC_Exception $Exception)
    {
        $Exception -> ExceptionWarning(get_called_class(), __FUNCTION__, $Exception -> Get_Parameters(__CLASS__, __FUNCTION__)[0], 0);
    }

    try
    {
        if(empty($Name))
        {
            throw new MarC_Exception(UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_MAIN_CLS, UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_MAIN_FNC, UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_MAIN_PRM, UniCAT::UNICAT_EXCEPTIONS_SEC_PRM_MISSING);
        }
    }
    catch(MarC_Exception $Exception)
    {
        $Exception -> ExceptionWarning(get_called_class(), __FUNCTION__, $Exception -> Get_Parameters(__CLASS__, __FUNCTION__)[1]);
    }

    /*
     * checks attribute name;
     * sets attribute to chosen element;
     * sets order to list of used orders
     */
    if($this -> Check_AttributeName($Name))
    {
        $this -> Set_SelectedElementAttributes($Order, $this -> Elements['sub']['set'], $Name, $Value);
        $this -> Set_OrderToList($Order);
    }
}
```

Comment: Why are you doing so much try { } catch { }? This is not how you should manage exceptions. And what is the exact question? Because I was thinking that you need way to call method like this, but you already done it. So?

Comment: @Arius: I asked because I was not sure if it is _legal_ to use `__call` to call not-existing method - and if not, how to do that in else way. Too many exceptions? I would not say. At least it is much better readable - than if there would be sequence of exceptions encapsulated in one.

Comment: I'm not saying that there is too many exceptions :) It's good to have control over methods. I'm only not sure that catching them should be in this class and maybe validation should look a little bit different, but this is more about architecture so don't take it serious :) And about __call - it is first of all used for situation like yours. Cheers!

Comment: @Arius: Yes, this is my the first usage of `__call` method. And about architecture: I don't think that checking should be placed in other class. Yes, it may be useful in some cases, but I don't think so in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `__call` here. But please be aware that **in most cases there is no need of using methods with 4 arguments or more**. Uncle Bob in "[Clean Code](http://www.goodreads.com/book/show/3735293-clean-code)" recommends max 3 parameters and 1 or 2 are the best. You can achieve this for example by encapsulating arguments to one object.

Example code for your case:

```
class TestClass
{
    public function __call($name, $arguments)
    {
        $nameArguments = explode('_', $name);
        $methodName = 'Set_SelectedElement'.$nameArguments[1];

        if(method_exists($this, $methodName) && count($arguments) > 1) {
            return $this->$methodName($nameArguments[0], $arguments[0], $arguments[1]);
        }

        return 'Noooooo.';
    }

    protected function Set_SelectedElementStyle($element, $name, $value = null)
    {
        return 'Style for '.$element.': '.$name.': '.$value;
    }

    protected function Set_SelectedElementAttribute($element, $name, $value = null)
    {
        return 'Attribute for '.$element.': '.$name.'="'.$value.'"';
    }
}

$testClass = new TestClass();

var_dump(
    $testClass->Person_Style('font-family', 'Arial'),
    $testClass->Element_Attribute('name', 'CustomName'),
    $testClass->Person_Style('font-family'),
    $testClass->Super_No('test', 'test')
);
```

Effect of var_dump will be as follow:

```
string 'Style for Person: font-family: Arial' (length=36)
string 'Attribute for Element: name="CustomName"' (length=40)
string 'Noooooo.' (length=8)
string 'Noooooo.' (length=8)
```

Comment: I know that functions with 4 or more arguments are _hell_ and I try to avoid their usage. And for this I defined that method with four arguments as protected.